# Call Python 3.x functions in Java

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, module

I want to call Python functions in Java. I know there is Jython, which comes with the PythonInterpreter for Java, but sadly it only supports Python 2.7.

For a better explanation of what I want to do. Let's say I have the following Python code in a given file:

```
@staticmethod
def my_first_function():
   print("Hi!")

@staticmethod
def my_second_function():
   print("Hi again!")
```

I want to be able to **EXPLICITLY** call functions like this in Java now:

```
PythonToJava pythonToJava = new PythonToJava("my/python/script/path");
pythonToJava.my_second_function(); 
pythonToJava.my_first_function();
```

How can I use/call a Python module/script/class/etc. in Java?

Comment: Try Py4J, it allows to define java interface to a python code https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html#implementing-java-interfaces-from-python-callback

Comment: I dont want to call Java functions in Python. I want to call Python functions in Java.

Comment: That's what the link I sent you is doing, please read - *"... Py4J allows Python classes to implement Java interfaces so that the JVM can call back Python objects..."*

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to implement that with my example code?

Comment: Sure, here's the example: https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html#implementing-java-interfaces-from-python-callback  There is python code defining an interface and java code to call it.

Comment: @Faram Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the Runtime.exec() method? Just do `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python script.py arg1 arg2")`. Runtime is a class from the java.lang package, so you don't need to do any fancy import.

[More info here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec.htm)

EDIT

Ok, not too easy to manage if you have lots of functions. On the other hand if you don't mind a bunch of wrapper files just do a bit of code to build one automatically for each function.

Check out this little piece of Python code. Just replace `foo` with whatever your huge module is called, and you're good to go.

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import foo

f_list=[o[0] for o in getmembers(foo) if isfunction(o[1])]
for x in f_list:
    print("Build "+str(x))
    with open("helper_"+str(x)+".py","wt") as f:
        f.write("""import foo
import sys

arg_list=sys.argv[1::]
print(foo.{x}(*arg_list))""".format(x=x))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to do. The problem here is, that I can't call a specific function. I've got a Python module with hundred of functions. I want to be able to call them individually. I know that I could do that with arguments (and switch case in the python script) or that I could put each function in a separate file, but that would be crazy. Considering that I need to debug here and then, it would be a problematic approach, too.

Comment: @TheOnionMaster Got it, please check out the edit to my answer. Is that un-crazy enough?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!